# How to keep drag gable element always on top

Tags: jquery

How

1. to keep drag gable element always on top of other drag gable
   elements on the page
2. How to bring the element on top of other drag gable elements on the page as soon as the mouse down event is triggered

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
     </script>

    </head>


       <style>
        body{width: 100%;height:100%;background: 
         url('./BG.jpg');margin:0;overflow: 
          hidden;}
           .bg{width: 100%;height: 100%; position: absolute;}
           #appear_image_div{width: 100%;height: 100%; position: absolute;z- 
           index: 10;opacity: 0.5; background:black;}
           #appear_image{
            -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
             animation-name: zoom;
             animation-duration: 0.6s;

            display: block; margin:auto;position: relative; z-index: 
            11;top:30px;height: 950px}




            @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
            from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
            to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
               }

                        @keyframes zoom {
                        from {transform:scale(0)} 
                        to {transform:scale(1)}
                        }

         #box {
         width: 150px;
         height: 150px;


           top: 0px;
           left: 0px;

          }

         #box1 {
         width: 150px;
         height: 150px;
         background-color: green;

         top: 20px;
         left: 50px;

        }

        #box2 {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: yellow;

        top: 50px;
        left: 100px;

       }

      #box4 {
       width: 150px;
       height: 150px;
       background-color: blue;

        top: 70px;
       left: 200px;
         }


       </style>
         <body>
        <div class="bg">

            <img src="./43.jpg"  id="box" >

            <img src="./45-1 copy.jpg"  id="box1" >

            <img src= "./45-2 copy.jpg" id="box2">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/CSSPlugin.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Draggable.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/TweenLite.min.js"> </script>

    <!-- this code for first image -->

        <script>

            // this for image one 
            Draggable.create('#box', {
            onClick: function(){
            var img=$(this).attr("src");
            var appear_image="<div id='appear_image_div' 
             onClick='closeImage()'></div>";
            appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img id='appear_image' 
            src='./43.jpg'/>");
            $('body').append(appear_image);
            },
            onDragStart: function(e){
               $('#box').addClass("dragging");
            },
            onDragEnd: function(e){
               e.stopImmediatePropagation();
               e.stopPropagation();
               e.preventDefault();
               $('#box').removeClass("dragging");
           }
       })
       function closeImage(){
        $('#appear_image_div').remove();
        $('#appear_image').remove();
    }

           $(document).on("click", '#box.dragging', function(){
           e.stopPropagation();
           e.preventDefault();
           //return false;
           alert('native click');
           });

          </script>

<!-- this code for second image -->
        <script>
                    // this for image two 
                    Draggable.create('#box1', {
                            onClick: function(){
                            var img=$(this).attr("src");
                            var appear_image="<div id='appear_image_div' 
                           onClick='closeImage()'></div>";
                            appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img 
                              id='appear_image' src='./45-1 
                           copy.jpg'/>");
                            $('body').append(appear_image);
                            },
                            onDragStart: function(e){
                            $('#box1').addClass("dragging");
                            },
                            onDragEnd: function(e){
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#box1').removeClass("dragging");
                        }
                    })
                    function closeImage(){ 
                        $('#appear_image_div').remove();
                        $('#appear_image').remove();
                    }

                        $(document).on("click", '#box1.dragging', 
                       function(){
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        //return false;
                        alert('native click');
                        });
                </script>



                <!-- this code for 3rd image -->
        <script>
                // this for image 3 
                Draggable.create('#box2', {
                        onClick: function(){
                        var img=$(this).attr("src");
                        var appear_image="<div id='appear_image_div' 
                        onClick='closeImage()'></div>";
                        appear_image = appear_image.concat("<img 
                         id='appear_image' src='./45-2 copy.jpg'/>");
                        $('body').append(appear_image);
                        },
                        onDragStart: function(e){
                        $('#box2').addClass("dragging");
                        },
                        onDragEnd: function(e){
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#box2').removeClass("dragging");
                    }
                })
                function closeImage(){ 
                    $('#appear_image_div').remove();
                    $('#appear_image').remove();
                }

                    $(document).on("click", '#box2.dragging', function(){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //return false;
                    alert('native click');
                    });
                  </script>





      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: @Carsten Lovbo i tried your modified code, but same error

Comment: I've didn't modify your code, I just changed the layout of your question so it was more easy to read